# Calculate the angle for the pulley system to reach equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

I am really confused by this question. The official way is to follow the assumed direction and come up am equation of

$F_{g left} - F_{gright} - F_{fricion 1}-F_{friction2} = 0$

But I come up with an idea to assume the surface to be frictionless and than just calculate

$F_{g left} - F_{gright} = 0$

As if the system reaches equilibrium in frictionless surface with a certain angle, it might as well in a surface with friction? I don't know if my hypothesis is correct.

I think the angle for angle $\theta$ in this question should be a range rather than just a single angle?

Can anyone explain if I am correct or wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hypothesis is of course correct.Your both the equations are also correct. But the second equation will give only one possible answer of all the cases . Just recall the problem where a block was kept on a rough inclined plane. There were many values of $\theta$ for which the block was in equilibrium(infact a range of values). Only when the angle was more than critical angle it starts sliding. Similarly here you will get a range of value for $\theta$. 
 But you should apply the inequality condition of static friction carefully.